# MVVMCross Android List Item Property Binding

Tags: android, listview, mvvmcross

I've got the exact same (like, I've diffed them looking for a typo) thing working on different lists in the same application. Does anyone know why my list item properties won't bind?

ViewModel - This seems to be working fine. I'm getting the correct number of rows, and I can see these ItemViewModels on the ItemSelected command. Therefore, the block below appears to be in working order:

```
public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items
{
    get { return _items; }
    set
    {
        _items= value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => Items);
    }
}

<namespace.MyListView
    android:id="@+id/my_list"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_title"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/my_item_rowlayout"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Items; ItemClick ItemSelectedCommand;" />
```

ItemViewModel - I can see these on the table's ItemSelected command, but none of the properties will bind to the layout.

```
    public string Path
    {
        get { return _path; }
        set
        {
            _path = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Path);
        }
    }

    public ItemViewModel()
    {
        Path = "some value";
    }


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/item_textview"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textSize="15dp"
      android:textColor="@android:color/black"
      tools:text="test text"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:textStyle="normal"
      local:MvxBind="Text Path" />
</LinearLayout>
```

While debugging MyListView, I can use GetChildAt to observe views that look like this:

```
base = {MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views.MvxBaseListItemView}
+       base    {Android.Widget.FrameLayout}    Android.Widget.FrameLayout
-       BindingContext  {MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.BindingContext.MvxAndroidBindingContext}   MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.BindingContext.MvxAndroidBindingContext
-       DataContext {Namespace.ItemViewModel}   Namespace.ItemViewModel
```

All of my properties are in there.

ListView:

```
[Android.Runtime.Preserve(AllMembers = true)]
public class MyListView: MvxListView
{
    public MyListView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs)
        : base(context, attrs)
    {

    }

}
```

From output:

```
    MvxBind:Error: 20.30 Problem parsing binding MvxException: Cannot terminate binding expression during option Path in Text Path
      at MvvmCross.Binding.Parse.Binding.MvxBindingParser.ParseEquals (System.String block) [0x00008] in D:\git\MvvmCross\MvvmCross\Core\Binding\Parse\Binding\MvxBindingParser.cs:80 
  at MvvmCross.Binding.Parse.Binding.Swiss.MvxSwissBindingParser.ParseNextBindingDescriptionOptionInto (MvvmCross.Binding.Parse.Binding.MvxSerializableBindingDescription description) [0x00091] in D:\git\MvvmCross\MvvmCross\Core\Binding\Parse\Binding\Swiss\MvxSwissBindingParser.cs:39 
  at MvvmCross.Binding.Parse.Binding.Tibet.MvxTibetBindingParser.ParseNextBindingDescriptionOptionInto (MvvmCross.Binding.Parse.Binding.MvxSerializableBindingDescription description) [0x0002e] in D:\git\MvvmCross\MvvmCross\Core\Binding\Parse\Binding\Tibet\MvxTibetBindingParser.cs:49 
  at MvvmCross.Binding.Parse.Binding.Swiss.MvxSwissBindingParser.ParseBindingDescription (MvvmCross.Binding.Parse.Binding.Swiss.MvxSwissBindingParser+ParentIsLookingForComma parentIsLookingForComma) [0x0000c] in D:\git\MvvmCross\MvvmCross\Core\Binding\Parse\Binding\Swiss\MvxSwissBindingParser.cs:195 
  at MvvmCross.Binding.Parse.Binding.Swiss.MvxSwissBindingParser.ParseBindingDescription () [0x00000] in D:\git\MvvmCross\MvvmCross\Core\Binding\Parse\Binding\Swiss\MvxSwissBindingParser.cs:178 
  at MvvmCross.Binding.Parse.Binding.MvxBindingParser.ParseTargetPropertyNameAndDescription () [0x0000c] in D:\git\MvvmCross\MvvmCross\Core\Binding\Parse\Binding\MvxBindingParser.cs:73 
  at MvvmCross.Binding.Parse.Binding.MvxBindingParser.TryParseBindingSpecification (System.String text, MvvmCross.Binding.Parse.Binding.MvxSerializableBindingSpecification& requestedBindings) [0x00015] in D:\git\MvvmCross\MvvmCross\Core\Binding\Parse\Binding\MvxBindingParser.cs:52
```

Comment: Does a hardcode string in the XML for the `TextView` `android:text` show up?

Comment: Yeah I figured it must be an issue with the view, but nope - hardcoded strings show up.

Comment: Would you be able to share the code for your custom `MyListView` class?

Comment: Thanks, I added the ListView (it's not doing anything though)

Comment: Hmm, all seem good. If you where to assign `_path`(`private string _path = "Testing";`) a starting value does that show up? And nothing interesting in the output window?

Comment: I did try that, no change. Interestingly, if I hardcode the text AND bind (any property, not Text) the row is blank.

Comment: Got something from output, investigating now

Comment: "Path" is reserved...renamed the property to "Name" and it works now. Ahhh. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Nice, glad you came right in the end :)

Answer (score 1):

After getting a hint to look at the output log, I found an exception and after a bit of searching it seems to have occurred when trying to use reserved keywords. "Path" is reserved, changing the property name resolved the issue.

Looking at the output log is key...